# Is there any way to split/explode and re-group lines in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a chart with multiple lines. Upon user request, I'd like to render the graph more readable (less lines) or more detailed (more lines). That would mean, that there would be for example a button "Split lines" and to "Group lines".
Now, while thinking about this, I guess this would be not an in-built feature, but an jQuery function, displaying then the corresponding lines. However, would have been nice to have a visual effect of line-splitting or grouping.

So, it should go from this here:

[image]

to this here:

[image]

I've put up a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/qu553bym/2/) to demonstrate it and would be curious about your ideas, experiences and workarounds.

The code, not really useful here:

```
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts({

    title: {
        text: "xxx",
        align: "center",
        y: 20,
        x: 0,
        style: {
            fontSize: "28px",
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || "black"
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: "",
        align: "center",
        x: -40,
        style: {
            fontSize: "13px",
            color: "#666666"
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: "xxx",
            align: "high",
            rotation: 0,
            textAlign: 'left',
            x: 10,
            y: -20,
            style: {
                fontWeight: "bold"
            }
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    credits: {
        href: "",
        text: "",
        position: {
            x: -185
        },
        style: {
            fontSize: "8px",
            color: "#666666"
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        layout: "vertical",
        align: "right",
        verticalAlign: "top",
        y: 55,
        reversed: true,
        itemStyle: {
            color: '#777',
            fontWeight: 'normal',
            fontSize: '12px'
        }
    },
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            connectNulls: true,
            shadow: false,
            lineWidth: 2,
            //color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2)',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: You already have this exact functionality as Highcharts provides it by default. You just need to click the item in the legend to toggle its line on/off.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. This is one option. But it's not the same effect, as there are up to five categories which form one group. So, this five lines should be "changed" into that single line, e.g. hidden and the single line appears. This would be so much nicer, more user friendly, and comprehensive...

Comment: Take a look at [drilldown](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown).

Comment: Drilldown may be one option, I would probably approach this by having the data stored in the appropriate arrays, and when the user clicks the button, simply remove the existing series from the chart, and add the others.  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.remove | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries

Comment: The drilldown looks pretty nice, exactly what I am looking for. However, I looked at all examples I could find - they are all with column charts only. I tried to manipulate some of them, in order to get the same result - but not on a categorical but temporal xAxis - for a line chart; but without success. Anyone knows of such thing?